# why do O_RDWR doesn't give me write and read permission in this code?

Tags: c, file, permissions, file-descriptor

I'm starting to be interested in `file descriptors` in `C`, i wrote the following code :

```
int main (void) 
{ 
    int fd1, fd2, sz;
    char *buf = "hello world !!!";
    char *buf2 = malloc(strlen(buf));

    fd1 = open ("test.txt", (O_RDWR | O_CREAT));
    printf("file fd1 created\n");
    write(fd1, buf, strlen(buf));
    printf("write %s, in filedescpror %d\n", buf, fd1);
    sz = read(fd1, buf2, strlen(buf)); 
    printf("read %s, with %d bytes from file descriptor %d\n", buf2, sz, fd1); 
    close(fd1);
    fd2 = open ("testcpy.txt", (O_RDWR | O_CREAT));
    write(fd2, buf2, strlen(buf));
    close(fd2);
    return 0; 
}
```

Normally:

- two files with read and write permissions are provided,
- `buf` is pasted into `fd1`
- `fd1` is read and the data is stored in `bf2`
- `bf2` is parsed into `fd2`

The first problem is that the permission that i get in the result aren't correct, what's happening is that something outside `buf2` is parsed into `fd2`.

Can anyone tell me what's happening, is my code wrong, or is what's happening is the expected behavior.

Comment: After `write(fd1, buf, strlen(buf));` the file pointer is at the end of the file. First `lseek(fd1,0,SEEK_SET);`. And you malloc one too little chars if you want to terminate what you read.

Comment: You never check for `open` errors.

Comment: `O_CREAT` assumes a third argument to open() to be present.

Comment: i added lseek, but it only solved the read probleme cause yes the cursor had to go back to the beginning of file, but this didn't solve the permission problem.

Comment: @wildplasser  i don't understand, it worked for me like this before, if i am to create only one file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to rewind the buff after the `write()`, and also add permissions (3rd arg of `open()`), this is a basic example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main (void)
{
    int fd1, fd2, sz;
    char *buf = "hello world !!!";
    char *buf2 = malloc(strlen(buf) + 1); // space for '\0'

    fd1 = open ("test.txt", (O_RDWR | O_CREAT), 777); // 3rd arg is the permissions
    printf("file fd1 created\n");
    write(fd1, buf, strlen(buf));
    lseek(fd1, 0, SEEK_SET);            // reposition the file pointer
    printf("write %s, in filedescpror %d\n", buf, fd1);
    sz = read(fd1, buf2, strlen(buf));
    buf[sz] = '\0';
    printf("read %s, with %d bytes from file descriptor %d\n", buf2, sz, fd1);
    close(fd1);
    fd2 = open ("testcpy.txt", (O_RDWR | O_CREAT));
    write(fd2, buf2, strlen(buf));
    close(fd2);
    return 0;
}
```